# Why does html code show up as different images in different browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser, character-encoding

(Discaimer: I only learned to code alone and upload some contents.)

I retrieved a symbol for a running person and used the code to build an html file to upload. The problem is that the image appears in different ways in different browsers.

A temporary mwe example.

- direct view in my site [ramoneando.com](http://ramoneando.com/mwe.html)
- code snippet:

```html
<h1><span style="font-family:'Segoe UI Symbol';color:black;font-size:40px;">&#127939;</span>runner</h1>
```

- (Desired) Image on local browser.

[image: original intended image]

## Why does this happen and how can it be avoided?

I actually am OK with the variants. The worse thing is that some look to the right and others to left. I would prefer to remain with the first image, in dark filling and looking to the right.

Comment: I mean no offense, but I am personally very hesitant to click away to an unknown domain posted on StackOverflow, and I suspect many other users may feel similarly.  Is it possible for you to post a snippet here, or perhaps recreate in CodePen or something?

Comment: "The problem is that the image appears in different ways in different browsers."... Ever heard of the Acid2 test? :-)

Comment: @NicolasMiari [Acid Test Website](http://www.acidtests.org/): _no longer reflects the consensus of the Web standards it purports to test, especially when it comes to issues affecting mobile browsers. The tests remain available for historical purposes_

Comment: Is this a bad question? Could I modify it, or shall it be expanded or deleted?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that not every computer has the font *Segoe UI Symbol* installed, so the ones that don't just display the character with code &#127939; in the default font.

For example, this is what the snippet looks like on my computer

[image]

(It used the font *Unicode Upper*, if you're interested.)

So what you can do is any of the following:

- Accept that the "Man running" symbol looks differently in different fonts and keep it the way it is
- Use Segoe UI Symbol as a webfont (this may be overkill for displaying just one icon)
- Or make a screenshot of the icon and turn it into a png file.

Comment: I would like not to use a png file so that it has more compatibility with text browsers. First option suggested is acceptable but would prefer to go to generic font. Is this possible? I removed `font-family:'Segoe UI Symbol';` but the result is still the same. Why is this? If I would choose the second option, how could I achieve that?